# How to solve this first order differential separable equation that has an $xy^2$ term?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Solve: 
>   $$(1+x+xy^2)dy+(y+y^3)dx=0$$

I know it's separable, I've tried transforming it with a variable $v = y/x$, but I can't get it to separate for integration. Help much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Write as $dy+ (1+y^2) (xdy + ydx) = 0$ or, equivalently, $dy + (1+y^2) d(xy) = 0$. Now it is clearly separable in variables $y$ and $v = xy$: $dy+ (1+y^2) dv = 0$.

Comment: Thank you! I just couldn't see the algebraic manipulation I guess.